# jupyter notebook not interrupted instantly

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

Some of my code just do not interrupt instantly (or forever ) when I click the interrupt button.

My code includes reading from mysql, dataframe and http request and loop.

It is interrupted when I interrupt in small amount of time after running(about 10 seconds)

I am closing the mysql and http connection on each loop.

Some other codes which include above functions is ok.

Comment: I use Jupyter a lot, and sometimes it's just garbage. Any operation that loads a lot of data into memory can cause an issue with Jupyter. Garbage collection does not function properly with Jupyter either. Best solution is to restart the Kernel and clear the contents, and then wait.